# DialogFragment is not Resumed after pressing Home Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have this code where a FragmentDialog opens at the top of the Main Activity. When i press home button and then again open the Fragment the onActivityCreated doesnt get called. Why is that?

Thank you

```
public class ProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {

private ProgressBar progress;
private TextView percentText;
private TextView descriptionText;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_screen,null);

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Please Wait....");
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",null);

    progress = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    percentText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percent);
    descriptionText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

    this.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        percentText.setText("Total Requests: 0");
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        descriptionText.setText("Analyzing Data....");
    }else{
        progress.setIndeterminate((boolean)savedInstanceState.get("indeterminate"));
        descriptionText.setText((String)savedInstanceState.get("description"));
        percentText.setText((String)savedInstanceState.get("percent"));
        progress.setMax((int)savedInstanceState.get("max"));
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the fragment lifecycle from the below link.

[Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

In this you can see that `onActivityCreated()` is called after `onCreateView()` and before `onResume()` of fragment.

So when you minimise your fragment by pressing home button, it will call `onPause()` method.

When you navigate back to your fragment, it will call `onResume()`.

Comment: It doesnt call onActivityCreated  when i navigate back to the fragment

Comment: That's what I am saying, it will not call onActivityCreated() because it will call onResume().

Comment: You can copy your bundle from onActivityCreated to another variable and check that variable in onResume()

Comment: And when onActivityCreated  is called in general?

Comment: Called when the activity's onCreate() method has returned.

Comment: So since your activity is not destroyed when your app is in background, onActivityCreated also doesn't get called